# How to connect to Amazon Athena using Simba ODBC

Tags: amazon-web-services, odbc, amazon-athena, dbi, simba

I am attempting to connect to Athena from RStudio using DBI::dbConnect, and I am having issues with opening the driver.

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(
  odbc::odbc(),
  Driver             = "[Simba Athena ODBC Driver]",
  S3OutputLocation   = "[s3://bucket-folder/]",
  AwsRegion          = "[region]",
  AuthenticationType = "IAM Credentials",
  Schema             = "[schema]",
  UID                = rstudioapi::askForPassword("AWS Access Key"),
  PWD                = rstudioapi::askForPassword("AWS Secret Key"))
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:983: 00000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '[Simba Athena ODBC Driver]' : file not found
```

In addition, this code returns nothing.

```
sort((unique(odbcListDrivers()[[1]])))
character(0)
```

It appears that my ODBC driver is unaccessible or incorrectly installed, but I am having trouble understanding why. I have downloaded the driver and can see it in my library.

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The error indicates that RStudio is not able to locate the driver . What machine do you have RStuido installed on and did you setup the ODBC driver as in https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/drivers/#odbcinst.ini ?

Comment: My RStudio is installed on MacOs 10.15.6 on my Macintosh HD disk. Athena does not require DSN, so I did not set up the odbcinst.ini or odbc.ini.

Answer (score 0):

The function arguments look strange. Remove the `[]` from `Driver`,  `S3OutputLocation` and `AwsRegion`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by validating the list of driver that R recognizes using `odbc::odbcListDrivers()`, then adjusting the name of the `Driver` argument accordingly. If R can't definitely identify the driver, setting `ODBCSYSINI=/folder_that_contains_odbcinst.ini/` in `.Renviron` solved for me.